# How to decide p and q in implication or conditional logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Let us take an example of compound proposition-

> If it is sunny, then we will go swimming.

Let ***p***: **it is sunny**

Let ***q***: **go swimming**

This proposition is written as: **p$\implies$q**

But it does not make much sense for the false case i.e., when p is true, and q is false (sunny, no swimming).

Now if we change the logic to: **q$\implies$p**

This makes more sense for the false case i.e., when q is true, and p is false (go swimming, not sunny).

**Questions:**

**1**. Which one of the two logical expressions is correct?

**2**. For a proposition to be written as p$\implies$q, how do you decide what is to be assigned to p and what is to be assigned to q?

Comment: Neither way is necessarily true. These statements "it is sunny" and "[we] go swimming" are english statements both of which may be true or false. Since we can't tell which, we cannot say whether or not the implications you state are true.

Comment: Saying "If it is sunny then we will go swimming" is a statement of intent. Assuming the statement is accurate, then it is indeed the case that if it is sunny and we don't go swimming, then we lied (the statement was false). "We only go swimming when it is sunny" is a different statement, denoted $q\to p$; that one says that if we are swimming, then it must be the case that it is sunny. The original statement was that if it is sunny, then it *must* be the case that we went swimming. But whether they make "sense" or not is not a question of mathematical logic, but of human experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propositional logic can be applied to real-world scenarios to describe the state of the world at some instant in time, usually the present. Your example introduces some confusion in this regard. At some instant in time, it could be sunny and we are *not* swimming.

My favourite example is: **If it is raining, then it is cloudy.** This does not mean that rain causes cloudiness. It means only that, at present, it is not both raining and not cloudy. Symbolically, we can write:

$~~~~~~(Raining \implies Cloudy)~~\equiv~~ \neg(Raining \land \neg Cloudy)$

Reversing this implication, we would have: If it is cloudy, then it is raining.

$~~~~~~(Cloudy \implies Raining)~~\equiv~~ \neg(Cloudy \land \neg Raining)$

I think you will agree that these are two very different relationships.